# CSS stylesheet not applying to html

Tags: python, html, css, mime

I am creating a website using Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/). I am trying to apply a css stylesheet to my html but its not working.

This is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="C:\sprout\leaf\templates\leaf\test.css">
```

Inside test.css:

```
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I tried using src instead of ref and earlier it was throwing a MIME type error. But it magically got fixed.

EDIT:

I fixed the error but now it throws a new one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdF1s.png

Comment: `ref="C:\sprout\..."`  This obviously won't work for anyone who is not logged in to your specific computer...  (I'm surprised `ref` worked at all.  Did you mean `href`?)

Comment: Since you're using django, the href should be something like `href="/static/css/test.css"`

Comment: Sounds like your server is sending the incorrect MIME type for this file, or `.css` files in general. Check your _Resources_ dev-tools tab.

Comment: @JohnGordon Its fine it it doesnt work for others, I'm am just testing it locally for now. Ref didn't work href didn't either, see the edit.

Comment: @JohnGordon 

It also throws this error when I run cmd

?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\sprout\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

So calling it from static won't work

Comment: @OskarGrosser where do I find the Resources tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use href as the attribute for the link to the file.

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\sprout\leaf\templates\leaf\test.css">
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, now it throws this error.

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.